# Running mongod service failed in Ubuntu 18.04.6

Tags: mongodb, service, ubuntu-18.04

`mongod` service failed to start. After rebooting the machine, checking if `mongod` is allowed to read and write in the files/directories, I don't find the root of the issue.

Checking the service, it fails:

```
(base) avy@machine:~$ sudo service mongod status
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-08-07 14:16:22 CEST; 2min 20s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 5230 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=100)
 Main PID: 5230 (code=exited, status=100)

août 07 14:16:22 machine systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
août 07 14:16:22 machine systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=100/n/a
août 07 14:16:22 machine systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I looked if the database (`dbPath` storage) was still owned by `mongod` and it is:

```
(base) avy@machine:~$ ls -l
drwxrwxrwx  5 avy mongodb  4096 août   6 13:08  mongodatabases
```

My config file is very simple and I did not write on it since I used MongoDB for the first time:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /home/avy/mongodatabases 
  journal:
    enabled: true

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
```

It seemed it was due to 27017.sock:

```
(base) avy@machine:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v5.0.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, 
connection attempt failed: 
SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

I changed the owning:

```
(base) avy@machine:/tmp$ sudo chown mongodb:mongodb mongodb-27017.sock
(base) avy@machine:/tmp$ ls -l
srwx------ 1 mongodb mongodb    0 août   7 15:27 mongodb-27017.sock
```

it is still failling.

UPDATE, answer to rickhg12hs comment *What's in /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log?*

```
(base) avy@machine:/var/log/mongodb$ ls -l
total 112156
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 114841063 août   7 17:37 mongod.log
```

There is only this file.

*Does mongod still have an old lock file that needs to be deleted?*

There is one in the desired dbPath:

```
(base) avy@machine:~/mongodatabases$ ls -l
...
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb        5 août   5 10:49 mongod.lock
...
```

I noticed something, let me know what you think about it

```
# the whole result of command
(base) avy@machine:~$ mongod
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T17:37:43.960+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T17:37:43.960+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T17:37:43.960+02:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T17:37:43.960+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T17:37:43.962+02:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T17:37:43.962+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T17:37:43.962+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T17:37:43.962+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T17:37:43.962+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":4638,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"machine"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T17:37:43.962+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.10","gitVersion":"bbf5bc7e16d1713c9349a09adf4901ca37472e66","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu1804","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T17:37:43.962+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"18.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T17:37:43.962+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T17:37:43.963+02:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T17:37:43.963+02:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":1019}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T17:37:43.963+02:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

When I focus on this line I saw it is still trying to run `dbPath` on `/data/db` contrary to what the config file tells:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T17:37:43.962+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":4638,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"machine"}}
```

besides it says the connection to the socket 27017 is not permitted

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T17:37:43.963+02:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}
```

so I tried this:

```
(base) avy@machine:~$ sudo mongod --repair --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

But this is the same problem

UPDATE 2

*What's in /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service?*

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Server
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# locked memory
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false

# Recommended limits for mongod as specified in
# https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-ulimit-settings

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

*Does the tail of the contents of /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log have some enlightening messages?*

I am not expert of database at all so "enlightening message" is difficult to judge for me. But I checked the behavior of a typical "good day" and the day it started to fail. I think this is due to a violent shutdown.

```
# a good day
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-04T23:49:03.773+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":0}}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-05T10:49:00.638+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
 # some lines
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-05T10:49:00.651+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":2027,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/home/avy/mongodatabases","architecture":"64-bit","host":"machine"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-05T10:49:00.651+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.10","gitVersion":"bbf5bc7e16d1713c9349a09adf4901ca37472e66","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu1804","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-05T10:49:00.651+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"18.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-05T10:49:00.651+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1","port":27017},"processManagement":{"timeZoneInfo":"/usr/share/zoneinfo"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/home/avy/mongodatabases","journal":{"enabled":true}},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-05T10:49:00.654+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/home/avy/mongodatabases","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
```

I shutdown without issue but it seems that today the schema is different:

```
{"a":"7FEA0E67261F","b":"7FEA0E551000","o":"12161F","s":"clone","s+":"3F"}}} # you see no {"exitCode":0}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T08:56:02.403+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
... # some lines
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T08:56:02.416+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":1932,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/home/avy/mongodatabases","architecture":"64-bit","host":"machine"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T08:56:02.416+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.10","gitVersion":"bbf5bc7e16d1713c9349a09adf4901ca37472e66","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu1804","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T08:56:02.416+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"18.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T08:56:02.416+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1","port":27017},"processManagement":{"timeZoneInfo":"/usr/share/zoneinfo"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/home/av/mongodatabases","journal":{"enabled":true}},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"}}}}
```

and then the `initandlisten` operation started to fail.

*Before mongod starts, there should be no lock file*

I removed all `.lock` files related to mongo in the whole machine.
I tried once again repair command

```
(base) avy@machine:~$ mongod --repair --dbpath "/home/avy/mongodatabases"
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T19:24:17.116+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T19:24:17.116+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T19:24:17.117+02:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T19:24:17.117+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T19:24:17.118+02:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T19:24:17.118+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T19:24:17.118+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T19:24:17.118+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T19:24:17.119+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":8346,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/home/avy/mongodatabases","architecture":"64-bit","host":"machine"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T19:24:17.119+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.10","gitVersion":"bbf5bc7e16d1713c9349a09adf4901ca37472e66","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu1804","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T19:24:17.119+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"18.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T19:24:17.119+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"repair":true,"storage":{"dbPath":"/home/avy/mongodatabases"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T19:24:17.123+02:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":28661,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Unable to read the storage engine metadata file","attr":{"error":{"code":38,"codeName":"FileNotOpen","errmsg":"Failed to read metadata from /home/mongodatabases/storage.bson"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T19:24:17.123+02:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":28661,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/storage_engine_metadata.cpp","line":91}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T19:24:17.123+02:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

---

About the version used:

```
(base) avy@machine:~$ mongod --version
db version v5.0.10
Build Info: {
    "version": "5.0.10",
    "gitVersion": "bbf5bc7e16d1713c9349a09adf4901ca37472e66",
    "openSSLVersion": "OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "ubuntu1804",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did everything formerly work, but now it does not? ... Or, is this the first MongoDB installation and you are trying to get everything to run properly?

Comment: What's in `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`?

Comment: Does `mongod` still have an old lock file that needs to be deleted?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I updated the topic to answer you as clearly as possible, and this is more convenient for console outputs. Now, to answer your first comment. I only installed once MongoDB on this machine. I did not make anything, except the updates proposed by Ubuntu. MongoDB worked perfectly fine yesterday until today after a reboot of my machine.

Comment: What's in `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`?  Does the tail of the contents of `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` have some enlightening messages? Before `mongod` starts, there should be no lock file.  If the lock file persists and/or isn't empty after `mongod` quits, `mongod` didn't shutdown properly.  Although `--repair` should have fixed that.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I checked your recommendations and answered in a second update.

Comment: There are several `dbpath`s in the various messages.  I'm not sure how that can happen.  If your data is important, I hope you have some backups.  :-(

Comment: @rickhg12hs oh no, haha I forgot to remove the real path, it does not matter when you see "/home/avy/Turf/données/mongodatabases" or "/home/avy/mongodatabases". I try to avoid to give the name of my paths and the real name of my machine too.

Comment: @rickhg12hs So you think I have to reinstall mongodb on my machine ? But keeping /home/avy/mongodatabases will conserve my data anyway, no ?

Comment: Is there any way to successfully run `mongod` using your current databases ... even if you launch `mongod` from the commandline?  If you can, a [`mongodump`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/) would be useful in case you need to `mongorestore` later.

Comment: No, I don't find anyway to run mongod on `/home/avy/mongodatabases` but I do with `sudo mkdir -p /data/db` followed by `sudo mongod`, it works but I have nothing in `/data/db` and in the same time `sudo service mongod status` indicates it is failling (very weird)

Comment: @rickhg12hs AH! I finally I found a way. 1. recreate an empty directory `sudo mkdir -p /data/db` 2. Copy and paste what there is in `/home/avy/mongodatabases` into `/data/db` 3. launch mongod `sudo mongod`. Now I have access to the database as it was before the crash. I will save it from MongoDB Compass. Thank you for your help and the time you take a sunday.